# Parsing a list of urls in python

Tags: python, urlopen

I'm trying to get some text from each url in a list using urlopen. However, it seems `urllib` is unable to read each url from the list as a string and keeps returning this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

When I try to convert each list object to string in the loop, it still can't read it:

```
URLError: urlopen error unknown url type: ['https>
```

My code looks like this:

```
for url in urls:
    str_url = str(url)
    page = urlopen(str_url).read()
    soup = bs(page)
```

the values come from a csv file where each url is a row. When printed in loop it looks like this:

['premierleague.com/players/3861/player/overview#']
['premierleague.com/players/2537/player/overview#'] 
...and so on

Comment: Could you provide the contents of `urls` and the actual stacktrace?

Comment: I was able to simulate this SO. The list urls is inside a list so it is breaking for example: [[url]]. Show us sample values for urls then we will help.

Comment: the values come from a csv file where each url is a row. When printed in loop it looks like this:

['https://www.premierleague.com/players/3861/player/overview#']
['https://www.premierleague.com/players/2537/player/overview#']
...and so on

Comment: try getting the first value of each array in your list of arrays. this will be a string which urlopen will know how to deal with

Comment: It looks like one of your URLs in your CSV has a typo e.g. `https>` rather than `https://`, try adding a `print url` so you can see which URLs are causing a problem.

Comment: @tijs Thanks so much, this was the issue. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each line contains only a url string. Then you can use file object to read each line which would return you a strings.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

for url in open('your_url_list.csv', 'r'):
    url = 'http://' + url if 'http' not in url else url
    source = urlopen(url).read()
```